# Polars slower than Pandas on cloud

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to Polars framework, I read that it is lot faster than Pandas with dataframes.
To test I tried to load a 2.5GB data into Polars dataframe and Pandas dataframe.
On my laptop stats are
**Polars ~8s**
**Pandas ~50s**
Being, super happy !
So, I next tried to create an azure function, read the same file stored on azure blob storage. This time the response were not so good.
**Polars ~435s**
**Pandas ~417s**
Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong.
Below is the simple code I am trying :
**for Polars:**

```
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions
import azure.functions as func
import polars as pd
import datetime 

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    lib = req.params.get('lib')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    source =os.environ('FILE_NAME')
    storage= {'account_key':os.environ('ACCOUNT_KEY')} 
    load_stime = datetime.datetime.now()
    df = pd.read_csv(source,storage_options=storage)
    load_etime= datetime.datetime.now()
    delta_time=(load_etime-load_stime).total_seconds()
    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.Following are the columns is the data file : {df.columns} and the shape of the data is {df.shape} also it took me {delta_time} seconds to load the data")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. the shape of the data is {df.shape}, it took me {delta_time} seconds to load the data.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

changed the polars to pandas for the other run.

Comment: Please don't `import polars as pd`.

Comment: Thanks @Dean, for the recommendation, but that change is not making any difference in the performance

Comment: Sorry if it seemed I was suggesting that would help performance. It's just going to be confusing if people see `pd.[polars_thing]`. As to your actual issue, I would be more interested in figuring out the huge discrepancy between the cloud read and local read independent of library. Are you using [datalake gen 2 storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) and is your function in the same region as your storage?

Comment: @Dean, Yes I am using ADLS gen2 storage for storing the files, the function and the storage are in the same region.

Comment: How fast is it locally if you do `pl.read_csv(file, n_threads=1)`?

Comment: with n_threads=1 ,  it loads the 2.5GB file in 16s

Comment: put these in your azure function `import fsspec;abfs=fsspec.filesystem(storage_options=storage)` then time how long `abfs.download(source, '/tmp/tmpfile.csv')` takes. That should take about 400 seconds. Then in the same run, time out `pl.read_csv('/tmp/tmpfile.csv')` and  `pd.read_csv('/tmp/tmpfile.csv')`

Comment: it is giving error as :  filesystem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'protocol'

Comment: oops `abfs.filesystem('abfss', storage_options=storage)`

Comment: @Dean, i see now the download time is 296s while loading into pandas df is 43s and loading into polars df is 7s and with threads=1 its 11s. Any recommendation on how the download time can also be reduced.

Comment: Other than ensuring your function app is in the same region as your storage, not really. Maybe there's an upgrade for the storage.

Comment: Thank you @Dean, you were really helpful.